# How do I hide C++ RTTI symbols?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, clang, obfuscation

Is there some easy/repeatable way to scramble RTTI symbols?

Some things that have already been done:

- static build -- Obviously this helps a lot as things get inlined between libraries and there is no clean interface like with a dynamic library. We want to do this in any case b/c the library works cross platform and this makes deployment a lot easier (just one fat library file)
- using "strip" -- At least on Linux (not sure if there is a Windows equivalent!) this will remove a good part of the symbols left floating around

However if I run "strings" on the library I can still see human readable symbols! After some investigating it seems like this is due to RTTI. All existing compilers seem to just use the function/class/etc. signature to generate the RTTI comparison values in code. This in-effect leaks source into the binary and gives the curious user insight into our secret sauce and how we make it.

Note:

- We can't build with -fno-rtti b/c the statically linked libraries we use are using RTTI internally. I think what I'm looking for is something that will work on the compiled executable, and not as part of the build process
- I've tried to do find a commercial product that will do this - but none list it in their feature list. A lot of the products seem to have questionable quality or are in some semi-abandoned state. Most seem to focus on scrambling the code and do all sorts of complicated transformation that hurt performance and aren't super critical for us.
- Manually scrambling all the symbols in all the libraries we use would do the trick.. but it seems like a maintainability nightmare...

Answer (score 2):

One easy solution is to build with a whole bunch of defines, for every name that you want to hide. Compile with `-DCFoo=a_1 -DCBar=a_2` and your classes `Cfoo` and `CBar` are gone from RTTI and other symbol tables.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Doing this in some automated way for all the leftover symbols seems like a bit of a challenge. Maybe someone will have an easier solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a C++ obfuscator. If you google quite a few pop up.

Comment: as I say in the question:

I've tried to find a commercial product that will do this - but none list it in their feature list. A lot of the products seem to have questionable quality or are in some semi-abandoned state. Most seem to focus on scrambling the code and do all sorts of complicated transformation that hurt performance and aren't super critical for us.